# How To handle multi-selection item in a scatterView

Tags: windows-7, multi-select, pixelsense

I am using Surface Toolkit Beta version for .NET 4.0. I am trying to select multiple items in a `ScatterView`. But I think I have to do it with code, can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you would want to implement multiple selection with a MT UI. In a traditional mouse & keyboard UI, the user can usually make a multiple selection by one of the following means:

- Clicking additional items while holding a modifier key (shift or ctrl) in order to extend the current selection, or
- drawing a selection rectangle / lasso around the items to be included in the selection.

Multitouch UIs normally don't provide for keyboard input (unless your scenario specifically requires it), so the question is: What kind of multiple selection would you want in your ScatterView? Something like a modifier key, or dragging a selection rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

The draggin selection rectangle  is the best idea ,
I have to do something with the touch events .